# Refresh/sync data from Mongodb Reactive using Spring Webflux

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-webflux

I am using Spring 5-Webflux and Mongodb Reactive.

I am able to pull the records/documents from Mongodb Reactive. But I would like to know how do I  push the data (sync/refresh my present records/documents) whenever there is any addition/deletion of the record/document in collection.

Basically keeping my client/UI in-sync with any record/documents in DB.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please show your latest non-working attempt at solving this problem. It is usually more instructive to see fixes to your code than to read someone else's solution. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Have you found an answer to your question. I’m currently trying to understand how you could use Webflux and mongodb do accomplish syncing with the ui